# System use case Vs. Software use case

Tags: analysis, use-case

I have known the difference between System use case and Business use case. But my teacher asked the difference between system use case and software use case. I am confused, I thought they were same, can anyone explain it for me?

Answer (score 0):

The term system is quite generic and can mean something that contains software, but also hardware or mechanical parts.  Think, for example of a robot.